# c# post empty octet-stream

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

working with a web form i am automating a call to this form.
lets say it is a web form with 2 fields to allow for file upload.
the content of this post when doing the post manually will post the second file empty.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"txtFileName_2\"; filename=\"\"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

with no data. so if i only need to upload a single file i need to provide that field as part of the content for the HttpClient but have not found a way to post an empty `octet-stream` yet.

I have tried:

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(Stream.Null), $"txtFileName_{i}", string.Empty);

content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream()), $"txtFileName_{i}", string.Empty);
```

both throwing error `System.ArgumentException: The value cannot be null or empty.`.

searching around i did not see anything about posting an empty file for multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

**COPY and PASTE error** 
looking at the error i just assumed it was yelling at me about the Stream.Null
NOPE, the method call has 2 overloads and if you supply a value for `fileName` the 3rd peram it expected it to have a value (fair enough)

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(Stream.Null), $"txtFileName_{i}", string.Empty);
```

appears to be working just fine.